# "every" vs. "each" vs. "each and every"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Consider the three sentences below:

> Sentence 1: "She loves every child with an equal amount of love."
>   Sentence 2: "She loves each and every child with an equal amount of love."
>   Sentence 3: "She loves each child with an equal amount of love."

Do the three sentences have equal meaning? Do all of the three sentences mean that, for example, if there are three children (A, B and C), she loves child A with X amount of love, she loves child B with X amount of love, and she also loves child C with X amount of love?

Comment: "with *an* equal amount"

Comment: @user3169 I edited my original post.

Comment: for a minute, I thought you had asked the difference between _'every vs. each'_ and _'every vs. each'_, and I was like, "what??"

Comment: You should rephrase the title by putting **each and every** at the end. Right now, it looks a little like a broken record.

Comment: Hello, does my title look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the sentences convey the same meaning; she loves all the three children equally.

Comment: How did you guess the quantity?

Comment: @vv Three sentences, three children..  Makes sense to me :D

Answer (score 1):

Three sentences basically cover the same meaning while "each and every" put a stronger emphasis than the others.